# Exception occurred resolving a log provider

Tags: c#

I'm using a Dot Net Framework and this log is happening every time I try to run. Can someone help me?

> Exception occurred resolving a log provider. Logging for this assembly Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ChangeFeedProcessor, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 is disabled. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'method')
> at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, Expression arg0)
> at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
> at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, Expression[] arguments)
> at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ChangeFeedProcessor.Logging.LogProviders.Log4NetLogProvider.GetGetLoggerMethodCall()
> at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ChangeFeedProcessor.Logging.LogProviders.Log4NetLogProvider..ctor()
> at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ChangeFeedProcessor.Logging.LogProvider.<>c.<.cctor>b__3_2()
> at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ChangeFeedProcessor.Logging.LogProvider.ResolveLogProvider()

Comment: the parameter named "method" is null...

Comment: Hi Matheus, Could you share the relevant pieces of code? That way we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason for the issue may be a tree shaking of Serilog.dll (e.g. due to PublishTrimmed=true). As a workaround, you can force compiler to include the missing method into the package:

```cs
// this is a dummy call to Serilog.Log.ForContext() to prevent this method from being trimmed by tree shaking:
Serilog.Log.ForContext("DummyLogger", new { DummyLogger = "dummy call Serilog.Log.ForContext()" }, false);
```

As a result, in the bin output I had a Serilog.dll with `Log` class lacking [this method](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/653260089620944516cbd874449f3c4bd02edc0e/src/Serilog/Log.cs#L94):

```cs
public static ILogger ForContext(string propertyName, object? value, bool destructureObjects = false)
```

which is essential for Liblog, requested [by this code](https://github.com/damianh/LibLog/blob/7b1cf28df0dc111f49fde0a3b4927d889417ebfd/src/LibLog/LogProviders/SerilogLogProvider.cs.pp#L71):

```cs
var method = logManagerType.GetMethod("ForContext", typeof(string), typeof(object), typeof(bool));
```

In our case, the solution was to sync Serilog.dll dependency accross the projects. And add a dummy call to make sure the missing method is included in the binaries.

It would also be a good idea to check the `[...].deps.json` file in the output folder to see actual version of Serilog.dll used in the compilation.

Just for the reference, this was my error stack trace (a bit different from yours, but the same idea):

```
Exception occurred resolving a log provider.
Logging for this assembly Quartz, Version=3.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f6b8c98a402cc8a4 is disabled.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'method')
   at System.ArgumentNullException.Throw(String)
   at System.ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(Object , String )
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression , MethodInfo, Expression, Expression, Expression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression , MethodInfo, IEnumerable`1 )
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression , MethodInfo, Expression[] )
   at Quartz.Logging.LogProviders.SerilogLogProvider.GetForContextMethodCall()
   at Quartz.Logging.LogProviders.SerilogLogProvider..ctor()
   at Quartz.Logging.LogProvider.<>c.<.cctor>b__3_0()
   at Quartz.Logging.LogProvider.ForceResolveLogProvider()
```